# Persistent Cookie is not working in cross browser's

Tags: asp.net, cookies

I am trying to set a persistent cookie from my asp.net application. when i try to store a value using IE browser and tries to get the value from Mozilla or chrome browser and it is not working.

- Is it possible to get the same persistent cookie value across all browsers?
- Is persistent cookie is browser independent?

I have used the below URL for persistent cookie.

URL:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31914/Beginner-s-Guide-To-ASP-NET-Cookies#9

and is  I've been using the below code :

```
public void SetPersistentCookies(string name, string value){
    HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(name);
    cookie.Value = value;
    cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(12);
    Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
}
 public void GetPersistentCookies(string name)
{
    //Retrive Cookie by cookies name
    HttpCookie cookie  = Request.Cookies[name];
    Response.Write(cookie.Value);
}
```

can you guys help me to resolve this issue with a sample?

Thanks,
Anbu

Answer (score 1):

No, cookie is not accessible across browsers. Persistent cookie is a cookie that doesn't disappear when browser is closed. Browser is responsible for managing cookies it stores, and each browser can have independent way of storing them.

What is more - I think this article is a bit outdated, check following link for 'fresher' info - [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178194.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Cookies are browser dependent. Main purpose of cookies is to store some data on client end or for specific client.

**1.Is it possible to get the same persistent cookie value across all browsers?**

No, If you want to access some value on different browsers then you should go server side.

**2.Is persistent cookie is browser independent?**

No, They are browser dependent. They will persist only on the browser where you had visited your page. I think you are confused about persistent.

**Persistent** means you are defining some time duration for cookie to exist. After this time it will deleted by browser.